# SQL Table records inserting in middle issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am fetching data from SQL Server database with standalone application & sending data to API & following is my logic:

1. I am syncing data from a single table.
2. I keep an count of the data synced in text file.
3. Next time I want to sync data, then I pick the count from text file & query the records with by using a `BETWEEN` clause. So I get new records every time.

My code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   
    (SELECT 
         *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY logdate) AS RowNum 
     FROM   
         tabletobesynced 
     WHERE  
         logdate IS NOT NULL) AS LogTable 
WHERE  
    LogTable.rownum BETWEEN 5000 
                        AND (SELECT Count(*) 
                             FROM tabletobesynced) 
    AND logdate IS NOT NULL
```

All was working well & good till the SQL Server started inserting records in the middle & not at the end.

For example: if table has 1 to 10 records then when 11th record was inserted it should be after 10th record but somehow the record was inserting in middle somewhere. This data is being inserted from third party services like Biometric Device.

Can you guide me to any solution?

Comment: *"SQL Server started inserting records in the middle & not at the end."* - In a relational database, tables are unsorted - meaning there is no such things "at the end" or even "in the middle". You can not base anything on the order of records you get from a select without an `order by` clause, since it is arbitrary.

Comment: For above mentioned reason, it's not a good practice to refer on something like position of row inside a table. You're probably better off with checking timestamp of row (maybe you have it in _logdate_ column ?), and process only records whose timestamp is bigger than time of previous processing.

Comment: You also can insert this entire data before syncing into another table,so it won't be affected by DML/DDL operations

Comment: @TheGameiswar the sync process runs every 1 hour. so new data is inserted every hour.

Comment: It's not the insert which is causing the problem, its the selection. Your table probably does not have a primary key. When you create a Primary Key the data is most of the times retrieved in the order of the index. But its always better to use your own ORDER BY clause to avoid any problems in future

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

You don't specify how data is getting into the table.  If you want to preserve the insertion order, then you can use an identity column:

```
create table tabletobesynced (
    tabletobesyncedId int identity primary key,
    . . .
);
```

Then you can use this id when you query the data by using `order by`:

```
order by tabletobesyncedId
```

Comment: Data is getting into the table through third party which is not in my hands. It is indeed a Biometric Device for Punching In & Out for Employees, Employee Punch data is inserted into the table by third party services,

Comment: @Anup . . . The table can still have an identity column.  The third party can insert using a view that hides the identity column.